# Reversed TF-IDF in Python

Tags: python, tf-idf

Can I reverse or offset the TF-IDF score such that MORE COMMON terms will 
contribute more to the final score?

I would like to find the most common set of words in the corpus, that isn't unique to any small subset of documents.

Comment: This seems to be against the nature of TD-IDF (to give a higher score to the more common terms). Have you thought about a simple frequency count? Or perhaps you could find a data cleansing technique that would reveal the most common words? Or I can give you a simple answer: [The be to of and a]. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about simply using counts, but this doesn't take into account the fact that I need the words not to be unique to a small subset of documents. E.g. a word could have a high count, although it is used only in 20% of the corpus.

Comment: Take the inverse value for use in the ranking: 1/TF-IDF.  The most common words will have the highest scores.

Comment: Thanks James, I'll use that method.

Comment: Did what james say work? Is it that straightforward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a very old post, but none of the suggestions in the comment section works well.

The "1/TF-IDF" one only gives you words that are rare throughout documents.

Remember that TF-IDF not only deprecates prevalent words but also rare words.

I have recently achieved your goal by using the "tf" and "idf" statics with the following steps:

1. Within each document, create a new statistic (Rev_tf_idf) by dividing **tf** with **idf**. (The original Tf_IDf is **tf*****idf** )
2. Group by words and sum up **Rev_tf_idf** within the group.

I found that words with higher **Rev_tf_idf** are those that are prevalent throughout all documents in my own data.

Hope this would work for those who have the same inquiry.